# Android in app billing, how to fetch prices in $

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

I have integrated in app billing in my app, using billing helper queryinventory method :

```
inAppBillingHelper.queryInventory(
```

I am able to get the prices of purchased inventory and items that are available for purchase. The problem is the prices for this items are coming in INR. But on my play console i have added the prices in $ not in INR.

I have 2 questions here :

1. Why is google play returning me the prices in different currency then what i set ?
2. Is there any way i can force it to return prices in $ ??

When the user click on buy, the prices shown in Google play purchase screen is in $ though. The issue is only when we fetch the prices manually.

Thanks
Pranay

Answer (score 1):

Please check this in app billing documentation first: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153485?hl=en

In the Support Currencies section, it states that `At this time, you can sell in-app items in your home currency, which is generally the currency for the country registered on your Developer account.`

So it would be able to return prices in US dollars, if the registered home country of your account is US.

Comment: the register home country for dev account is US. Infact when purchase is trigger the prices are coming in $. This is only issue when i am fetching the prices manually.